# VSTS, create build definition gets AllowScriptsAuthAccess error

Tags: oauth, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

long time listener, first time caller!
I've spent two days searching for an answer to this so hopefully someone here may be able to help.

I've set up a personal/free VSTS instance and created a project.
One of the first tasks I want to do is setup the build pipeline, so create a new pipeline, define the agent pool as VS2017, connect to my Github repo etc, all of which is fine.

Next I try to add an Agent Job, again choosing VS2017 as the agent.  With no other options chosen, if I try to save the build definition I get the following error message (and cannot save it);

`The AllowScriptsAuthAccess build option is not supported in API versions greater than 4.0.`

Allow scripts to access the OAuth token is **unchecked** on the Agent job configuration under phases *and* on the Build/Options tab (slider set to **disabled**)

I've googled and searched for all sorts of stuff to try and find someone with the same problem but it's almost like I'm the first to discover this - which is highly unlikely!!  It has almost driven me to using Bing to search for a solution, but let's not get carried away.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For the Agent pool, do you mean the `Hosted VS2017` Agent? Tested on my side and cannot reproduce the issue. What about other team projects? Just try 
 creating a new team project, then create a new build pipeline to check if that works...

Comment: Thanks.  I have created several projects and organisations to see if this is an isolated issue, but it occurs in all orgs and projects.

Comment: We cannot reproduce this issue. Does it still occur? Which tasks did you add? Can you provide a screenshot for the error?

Comment: I'm having this same issue.  It's a new build project.  Trying to build/deploy Azure Streaming Analytics. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-tools-visual-studio-cicd-vsts).  Even with just the Nuget Restore build step enabled, I still see this error.  EDIT: it's not even about queuing the build, I can't even save it!  I get the error by just selecting "Save".

Comment: I tried on another instance, hosted in another region and was able to save my build definition.  So I'd say this is a South Central US problem, which has been down for the last couple days (9/5/2018)

Comment: @EJA We have fixed the issue in South Central US. Can you still reproduce this issue?

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT  I cannot reproduce in South Central US.  Agreed that this is now fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

So it turns out that turning off the "New YAML pipeline creation experience" and "New Navigation" under preview features fixes the problem, insofar as I can now create and save a build pipeline without the error.

Also, if you have "Build YAML Pipelines" enabled under preview features for the Organisation, you get the "View YAML" link that I was missing also.

Thanks all for your help.  I'd be interested to know the root cause of this still. I'll update the Microsoft support ticket with the same and post back here if they have any insights.

Comment: I suffered the issue you described and had to _enable_ New YAML pipeline creation experience.

Comment: Where do I find the switch? I am looking in Organization settings.

Comment: @KirstenGreed Click on your profile icon (top, right-hand corner) and select Preview Features menu item.

Comment: @JakubKonecki I see it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's an similar issue here:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/123012/getting-multiconfiguration-build-option-not-suppor.html

Seems the build template was broken. So, you can try with other build templates or starting over with an empty template, then add the needed tasks manually to check if that works.

Besides, you can try below things:

- Clean the caches on your client machine, also clean the browser
  caches, then check it again. See [How to clear the TFS cache on
  client machines](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsalm/2013/12/17/how-to-clear-the-tfs-cache-on-client-machines/).
- Create a new team project and create a new build pipeline within the
  new team project to check if that works

Comment: hi, thanks. I did see that post a while back, and I've tried using a task group but I get the same issue, as the OAuth setting belongs to the Agent job that "contains" the task group or individual tasks.

As above, I've tried creating another org, several different projects, and I've tried using VSTS repo and GitHub repo's but all have the same issue.

Important to note that this is VSTS Free, not corporate - so it behaves a little differently

Comment: @not_A_dev Yeah, I also tested with the free VSTS and cannot reproduce this issue. Seems it's an specific issue to your VSTS account. Suggest you submitting an issue on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is a bug in the VSTS system and it will likely be fixed soon.  But for the time being, I found a workaround:

I was also getting the AllowScriptsAuthAccess error and struggled with it for hours.  I don't think any of the configuration settings you mentioned have anything to do with it (free account, GitHub, OAuth token unchecked).
To solve it, I converted the Agent Job to YAML (which is as easy as clicking "View YAML" in the upper right).  Save the code to a file named .vsts-ci.yml, and save this in the root folder of your solution.  Commit/push the new file, then queue the build.  (Note that the conversion to YAML is one-way, so you may want to Clone your build.)

That should get rid of the AllowScriptsAuthAccess error.  After that I had to add a few variables, but then it's just a matter of following the error messages.

I hope this helps.  Sorry I can't answer this more authoritatively.  Please post a comment if I am missing any steps.

Comment: Can you still reproduce this issue?

Comment: I can't see the "View YAML" you mention.  I can add an agent job, but there is nowhere to convert it or the build def to YAML... could you post a screen snip of this option perhaps?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it turned out that I didn't have Build Admin permissions in VSTS for the project. Not a very helpful error message for this.

Comment: thanks - tried adding myself as build admin everywhere, but still getting the same issue...